# preg_grep returns NULL

Tags: php, regex

I have the following array:

```
$data = array(
  "Between 'Fluent, spontaneous, almost effortless flow' and 'Communicates spontaneously and reasonably fluently even in longer complex speech'",
  "Between 'Good use of a fairly broad vocabulary range sometimes with gaps' and 'Good range of vocabulary used in their field and most general topics but with gaps'"
);
```

And I am trying to put the content of the single quotes into another array:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){                      
    if(preg_match("/^Between/", $data[$i])){
        $pattern = "/(?:^|\s)'([^']*?)'(?:$|\s)/";
        $candos_split = preg_grep($pattern, $data[$i]);
    }
}
```

But $candos_split returns NULL even if I have tested my regular expression and it works without problems. I know it must be something stupid but I can't see where the problem is.

Comment: This looks like it might break on input like `"Between 'do's' and 'don'ts'"`

Comment: `Warning: preg_grep() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given` is what I get.

Comment: And also, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' on line 2` - array should be defined as `$data = array(...);`

Comment: Shouldn't the $data array be defined as `$data = Array(...)`??

Comment: Why not grep `^Between` into an array, then grep `$pattern` on that array?

Comment: You are right @GerbenJacobs, preg_grep expects an array as second parameter. Is it possible to use a regular expression against a string and get an array containing all the possible matches?

Comment: You are right @Yeah, my code doesn't look like that. I am use the real array() format in my code. It was only for display purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_grep()` greps arrays, not strings. You might wanna use `preg_match_all()` instead:

```
$data = array(
  "Between 'Fluent, spontaneous, almost effortless flow' and 'Communicates spontaneously and reasonably fluently even in longer complex speech'",
  "Between 'Good use of a fairly broad vocabulary range sometimes with gaps' and 'Good range of vocabulary used in their field and most general topics but with gaps'"
);

$pattern = "/(?:^|\s)'([^']*?)'(?:$|\s)/";
$matches = array();
foreach($data as &$line) {                     
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $line, $m))
        $matches = array_merge($matches, $m[1]);
}
```

`print_r($matches)` will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Fluent, spontaneous, almost effortless flow
    [1] => Communicates spontaneously and reasonably fluently even in longer complex speech
    [2] => Good use of a fairly broad vocabulary range sometimes with gaps
    [3] => Good range of vocabulary used in their field and most general topics but with gaps
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use this in a match all way

**edit** If you *Join* all the source array elements with a newline `\n` char to form a single
string, you can then call match_all on that string, you should get a single array
of all the different quoted items.

```
 # '/(?m)(?:^Between|(?!^)\G)[^\'\n]*[^\S\n]\'([^\'\n]*)\'(?=\s|$)/'

 (?m)                    # Multi line mode
 (?:
      ^ Between          # 'Between'
   |                     # or,
      (?! ^ )
      \G                 # Start at last match
 )
 [^'\n]*                 # Not ' nor newline
 [^\S\n]                 # Non - newline wsp     
 '
 ( [^'\n]* )             # (1)
 '
 (?= \s | $ )
```